# Mark method of Java runtime as deprecated

Tags: java, deprecated

I want to make my team mates aware that String.replace() shall not be used (because many of our developers are not aware of the regular expression arguments) and advice them to use StringUtils.replace() instead.

I can do so by telling them, by putting focus on that in code reviews, by writing custom rules for Findbugs, CheckStyle or other tools, but I would rather like to document this in the code and make the *compiler* aware of my intention.

If String were a class in my own code, I would simply add deprecation annotations. Is there a way to add **deprecation annotations for classes, which I don't have the sources** for?

(And no, I don't want to compile the JDK myself as a workaround :)

Comment: String.replace() doesn't take regexps, does it ? Are you thinking of String.replaceAll() ?

Comment: What more are you looking for if Checkstyle flags this as an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No.

There are viable alternatives, such as enabling or adding rules in/to your groups' style / bug checker tool (FindBugs, PMD, CheckStyle, etc).

---

However I think you are taking the wrong approach here.  If I was one of your developers, I'd be rather offended at the implication that I was "too stooopid" to use `String.replace()` or `String.replaceAll()` correctly.

If you really have a problem with your developers not understanding, then you need to either educate them some more, or (if they really are stupid ...) replace them.

And if the real problem is that your codebase is infested with incorrect usage, then what you need to do is a code audit; e.g. `grep` the codebase for all occurrences of that method name, and inspect them.

Comment: Surely you may feel offended as much as you want. However, this is not about a single hero developer, this is about a distributed team. It does not matter whether _the author_ understands his/her code, in a large distributed team _everyone_ must understand _everyones_ code. Therefore all ambiguities shall be avoided. I surely prefer education, but I see new team mates all the time, so I must have strict rules in the code (and tools). BTW: My team mates are typically very happy about such measures, as I help them to avoid mistakes. They don't feel "restricted in their creativity"...

Comment: Whatever.  The bottom line is that the answer is still No.

Answer (score 1):

That's a compile time utility which is validated by IDE, so there is no another way to add deprecation on methods, You have to change sources of JDK and compile them.

Perhaps if You are using build tools check if there are any plugins which You can tell fail the builds if particular method was called